# Convert numerator and denominator with decimals

Tags: fractions

Say I have a set of decimals such as `[.25, .5, .75]`. I want to convert the numerator and denominator of their fraction equivalents, such that:

```
.25 = 4
.5 = 2
.75 = 1.333
```

I don't know what these numbers are beforehand, and this will be computed such that it is always a floating point or decimal value. If it helps, the number will always be less than 1.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It looks like you have taken [reciprocals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse)

Comment: As the folloowing: $\frac{1}{0.25},$ $\frac{1}{0.5}$ and $\frac{1}{0.75}.$

Comment: Please note that $.25=4$ is a false statement.  $.75=1.333$ is false that way and because $1.333 \neq \frac 43$. What you are asking is just to take the inverse of the incoming number to get the outgoing number and presumably round to three decimals.

Comment: I am talking about reciprocals.

Answer (score 0):

A number like $.75$ is just shorthand for $75/100 = 3/4$.